# Flexbox: Prioritize for content width of a certain child

Tags: html, css, flexbox, image-gallery

I have the following setup:

[image]

Each row of images is wrapped in a flexbox container.
In the second line I'd like the portrait images to shrink in height and let the landscape image be responsible for the height.

Here's my [jsbin-Link](http://jsbin.com/nekatow/6/edit?html,css,output).

I've tried a couple of different things with various flexbox properties but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
&.type-2 {
  figure {
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-shrink: 1;
   flex-basis: auto;
  }

  .landscape {
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 2;
    flex-shrink: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: `align-items: stretch` defaults to the *tallest* in the *cross-axis*, not sure it can align to the *shortest*....